# Adding psuedo elements to <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, textarea

I recently stumbled upon [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/08/inspiration-text-input-effects/comment-page-1/#comments) and I decided to experiment with it.

I created a small contact form and all the `<input type="text">` tags display as they should but I'm having trouble with the `<textarea>`.

What I want is for the textarea to be bigger then the input boxes, which I got working by adding

```
.yoko-textarea::before{
    height:23em;
}}
```

The problem is that when you type something in it, and click somewhere else, the box dissapears. I want it to stay visible, like the `input type="text">` tags.

[Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/xs1vfjsx/)

The format is broken since I only added the relevant code. You can find the `<textarea>` at the bottom.

If anybody can help me with this issue, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `document.querySelectorAll` you're only selecting all ements of type `intput` and class `input__field`. You have to also include type `textarea` in there.

Replace this:

```
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input.input__field' ) ).forEach( function( inputEl )
```

With:

```
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input.input__field,textarea.input__field' ) ).forEach( function( inputEl )
```

Comment: I've been looking at the CSS the entire time, never thinking that the solution was one line in jQuery. Thank you so much.